# Build something like open atrium

Tags: 7, distributions

I just installed open atrium and was amazed how it works and how its made. It is made to work with just some clicks while installation. I want to build something like this. I just want to pre configure just blogs, gallery and forums and with some groups. Installation profile knowledge i need. what else should i know properly so as to build such a thing.

Comment: I'm the middle of building a Drupal site much like Open Atrium for a client. It's worth making sure that the important modules you need work well together and are stable before beginning the build. We chose to use Drupal 6 rather than 7 for this reason. Also be prepared to get your hands dirty with coding some bespoke modules.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're going to want to understand the relationship between [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og), [Spaces](http://drupal.org/project/spaces), [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context), [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) and possibility the [Persistent URL](http://drupal.org/project/purl) and [Strongarm](http://drupal.org/project/strongarm) modules. Aside from Organic Groups, they were all created by the same developer who started Open Atrium.

[Here is one very basic run-through about how Open Atrium works](http://drupal.org/open-atrium).

[Here is a description of how each of those modules factor into the OA structure.](https://community.openatrium.com/documentation-en/node/1951)

**Be warned**: I don't think I've seen a more complex site built with Drupal. Most of those modules are not only complex, but also genius.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you are wanting to get this involved in drupal installation profiles and how the sites work, it would be a good idea to research using [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush).  Its a command line tool for working and administering Drupal.